# With default configuration in VS code, unable to debug the python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to Python and VS Code and am trying to debug a simple python program via "F5" or "Run with debugger".

Whenever I try to debug a simple python program using the python extension, a pop up appears at the bottom right **"The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid."**

It suggests opening launch.json, but doesn't explain what to add.

How can I easily debug my new python program?

Comment: Please show the supposedly invalid configuration in your question. We can't figure out what we can't see…

Comment: Try selecting the folder containing the python executable and not the python executable itself.

Comment: @Steven -Please provide us with the content of the "launch.json" you set and the python script (.py file) you used for testing.

Comment: I got this problem where I stored the code on Github and developed the code on different computers where the version of Python was different. I found that switching the IDE with the same code caused Python not to be loaded. You can tell in VS Code by the lower toolbar in the bottom left corner what version of Python is loaded, and if you click it you can change it to the correct version. This should fix your problem.

Comment: This error is seen because you installed Python, but have not added it to your path. 

Once you add C:\Python<Version> to your PATH variable, and relaunch Visual Studio Code, you will successfully be able to debug.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was solved by adding `python.exe` in the python path in VSCode, in my case. See `File - Preferences - Settings`. Click the "Open Settings (JSON)" button. Make sure that this entry has `python.exe` at the end. `"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\<your_user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe"`

Comment: Open Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P)
Type Python: Select Interpreter, open it
Select the the python interpreter or enter the full path to the python interpreter

Comment: run python from the command line, choose the command line for the version that you want to use in Visual studio code: for instance, python or python3 or python3.9 in case you have multiple versions of python on your computer/server 
Then >>import sys and >>print(sys.executable) this will return python path. Copy and paste it into "python: python path" in VIsual code settings

Comment: The solution from mhc did not work, but the one of @Fhyarnir did make it.